# select dropdownbox appearing white on white on some machines but not mine

Tags: html, css

I have a select box that I have added some formating to that, this appears fine on my machine (mac os, running dark mode or light) across safari & chrome it appears the same for me, black font on lighter background. But on my colleagues machine (chrome on windows) it appears white on white. How can I resolve this and how can I target the appearance of the dropdown list specifically in the css?

```
  <select class="dark-input">
         <option>etc</option>
  </select>

  //shared class with input
 .dark-input {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  width: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  background: #ffffff1a;
}

//format Select box
select.dark-input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

[image: example of problem]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Option Select box showing different color in different Machine Like (Window, Ubuntu safari and) etc. Because of it's HTML default Select box, so that u need to create custom Select design box using JS..... just go here :https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select

Comment: thanks, because Im working in Angular, rathar then use jquery, I ended up using mat-select and overiding the styles to bring it back inline with what I had with the native box.